# Read excel sheet file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, excel, import

I wants to browse an excel file and read the files on browser using JavaScript in JSON format. As well as I wants to access all the elements contained by sheet either its key or value. I have to count no. of rows and columns of the sheet. As I have to use the keys to match within my application so I need an independent access on it.

My code :

```
    <html>
       <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
          <script>
             function handleFile(e) {
               //Get the files from Upload control
                  var files = e.target.files;
                  var i, f;
               //Loop through files
                  for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
                      var reader = new FileReader();
                      var name = f.name;
                      reader.onload = function (e) {
                          var data = e.target.result;
                          var result;
                          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                          var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
                          sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /* iterate through sheets */
                              //Convert the cell value to Json
                              var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                              if (roa.length > 0) {
                                  result = roa;
                              }
                              var roaKeys = [];
                                  for (var i = 0; i < roa.length; i++) {
                                      roaKeys.push(Object.keys(roa[i]));
                                  }
                              for(var j=0;j<roa.length;j++)
                              {
                                  console.log(result[j].Code);
                                  console.log(result[j].ElementName);
                                  console.log(result[j].OptionName);
                              }
                          });
                      };
                      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
                  }
              }
              //Change event to dropdownlist
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#files').change(handleFile);
              });
          </script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" id="files" />
       </body>
    </html>
```

I am not able to access rows and columns independently. Please guide me how can I do this?